# JavaFX FileChooser.showOptionDialog(stage) get the Stage from an other class

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am working for the first Time on an JavaFX project and here is my problem:

I hava a MainApp, from there I open the Main Window, there I have a MenuBar and from the MenuBar I open a new Window, this is called in the controller from the MainApp.

```
public void optionWindow() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/options.fxml"));
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("options");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    stage.show();
}
```

In this new window I have two buttons and one of them should open a FileChooser with a method in the OptionsController class.

```
public void updateOptions() {
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
}
```

MainApp start method:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/Application.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Application");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

My Problem is, how can I get the Stage? Because the Stage is in the MainAppController class. Is there any popular war to get stages and the primaryStage around?

thx 4 reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to a `Stage` by:

`Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow()`,

where node could be e.g. one of your buttons.

Another possibility is to set the `Stage` in the `OptionsController`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/options.fxml"));
Parent root = null;
try {
      root = loader.load();
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
OptionsController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setParentStage(stage);
```